# Can I connect low current inductors in parallel to get high current boost converter

Tags: inductor, boost, high-current

The image below is a 680uH and 4A inductor:

[image]

Can I use 5 of them in parallel to make a boost converter which has input current of 15A and inductance of 136uH. The converter is made of discrete components thus no recommended inductor can be found.

I think to do the same for the pi filter at output which is 10A max and will consist of two parallel 68uH inductors with 1mm wire thickness:

[image]

Comment: You could try, but each inductor may not be identical and one may take most of the current.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but consider doing a few other things first:

1. Raise operating frequency.  Voltage isn't indicated, but if this is average low voltage stuff (5-30V?), these inductances sound monstrously large for that.

   For current, non-bleeding-edge tech, I would choose values in that range for, oh I don't know, mains voltages or thereabouts?

   Example: 136uH 15A has 20% or 3A peak current ripple, at 100kHz, for ±160V applied, e.g. a buck converter from 320 down to 160V, or a bit slower for other ratios at the same input.  That is, V = L dI/dt, for dI = 3A, dt = 2.5µs (quarter a 100kHz wave -- quarter because peak, not p-p which would be half up and half down), and L = 136µH.
2. Rather than wiring everything in parallel / synchronously, do it out of phase (phase interleaved converter).  This is more of a priority with respect to transistor ratings, or these days even moreso just sheer layout limitations, but perhaps it's relevant here, too.  The disadvantage is more components: more inverter and filter stages repeated; more control complexity (hopefully solved with a single integrated controller, but if not, it can get quite baroque).  The advantage is, input and output ripple goes as 1/N for N stages in phase interleave.  Which greatly saves on capacitor ratings, which is actually a rather big deal for compact, high power designs.
3. Can you really not find bobbin-style inductors in those values?  They're fairly common around here at least [western markets].  But maybe I'm missing something from my perspective.

   3a. Does it have to be bobbin-style? There are other semi/fully shielded ferrite cored inductors available, and even composite/molded types with reasonable performance (some with Q over 100 at some frequencies).  If you're confining your search to THT, seriously consider expanding your capabilities.  It's not that much effort to use SMT once you have the tools/techniques, and product availability is tremendous.

Regarding the toroid pictured: beware, they can have obnoxiously high losses.  The yellow core pictured is most likely a Micrometals #26 powdered iron, little more than a resistor above 200kHz -- and quite lossy below there.  Its only advantage is low cost; it's only suitable for CCM (continuous current mode, read: low ripple fraction, typically under 10%) converters below maybe 50kHz.  Unfortunately, datasheets rarely tell you what material they actually used -- and supplier photos are spotty.

I do know, offhand, Bourns' 2200LL series for example, uses Kool-Mu (black; by Magnetics, Inc.), which is a reasonable powder material.  Still most suitable in CCM, but to higher ripple fraction (say 30%?), and at higher frequencies (100kHz, may be a bit more?).

Generally you want ferrite for lower losses (required for high ripple fraction i.e. DCM, such as peak current mode converters), and generally that means cut/molded core shapes with an air gap.

Comment: I did my calculations, this converter can boost 7V to 100V with more than 1.2A output, so input current can go 15A. The converter is around 120-150W. I an increase the frequency to take current ripple down but according to my calculations it is only 0.8A in the worst case. I searched for phase interleaved converter in the internet, they look cool but this is my very first boost converter I'll ever make so don't want to confuse yet. I could only find choke inductors at that current rating, my supplier is not that professional.

Comment: I am using a torroid, a choke inductor (https://cdn03.ciceksepeti.com/cicek/kcm69037033-1/L/toroidal-hat-filtresi-sok-bobini-pc-guc-kaynagi-kcm69037033-1-0b3de35a84eb434089d3e09268a26a14.jpg) to make a pi filter at the output (it's too lossy for boost converter L). The pi filter consists of 100uF cap - choke with unknown inductance (recycled item) - 10uF polyester respectively. The 100uF is the cap of boost converter and feedback loop is taken from that capacitors voltage. I was okay for unknow inductance because the cutoff frequency is way below switching frequency even the choke has small L.

Comment: Ok, filter is a good place to use those, yes. The losses reduce filtering a bit, but also help dampen it so you have a reduced transient response without having to add R+C snubbers or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The small bobbin inductor doesn't appear to be really capable of 4 A. In addition, of you place inductors close together, there may be some magnetic coupling which means the effective inductance will be different from what you calculate (+ or -, depending on the polarity of coupling).

Comment: Also wondering how the connection will perform, because of a multilayer or longer return path.